# Show arraylist in android frontend

Tags: java, android, list, listview, arraylist

I have been searching for ways to put an Arraylist onto a ListView in android but have not been able to do so. This is the program that I use, but it seems to work only for a String array and not for a List element.

```
List<Students> studentList = new ArrayList<Students>();
ArrayAdapter<Students> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Students>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                studentList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I need to find a solution where I can put this arraylist onto the listview without having to convert this into a STring array. Is any such thing possible?
Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: You have to make a Custom Adapter

Comment: Use Custom Adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override the adapter's `getView` method to implement your desired functioning:

```
ArrayAdapter<Students> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Students>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
        studentList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Let the system create and re-use the views
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Get the default android layout's TextView
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        // Get the students info (name or w/e)
        Students student = getItem(position);
        String studentName = student.getName();
        textView.setText(studentName);

        return view;
    }
};
```